# error CS0428: Cannot convert method group `OnClick' to non-delegate type `bool'. Consider using parentheses to invoke the method

Tags: c#, unity3d

Onclickでボタンをクリックすると(golds)から-=200するようにしたいのですが、
error CS0428: Cannot convert method group `OnClick' to non-delegate type`bool'. Consider using parentheses to invoke the methodとでました。　
どのようにすればよいでしょうか

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;
using UnityEngine.UI;
public class shop: MonoBehaviour {
    public int golds = 300;
    public Text scoreText;
    /// ボタンをクリックした時の処理
    public void OnClick() {
        Debug.Log ("Button click!");
    }

    void Start () {
        scoreText.text = "golds:" + golds;
        if (OnClick) {
            golds -= 200;
        }
    }

    void Update () {
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

以下のような方法は、いかがでしょうか？

---

①
gold変数保持のためのスクリプトを用意して、GameObjectにアタッチ。

```
public class MoneyBehaviour: MonoBehaviour{
    public int golds = 300;
}
```

---

②
shop.csは、Buttonコンポーネントを持ったGamenObjectにアタッチ。
moneyBehaviourには、①で作業したMoneyBehaviourを割り当て。

```
public class shop: MonoBehaviour {
   public MoneyBehaviour moneyBehaviour;
   public Text scoreText;

   void Start () {

       Button button = this.GetComponent<Button>();

       button.onClick.AddListener(OnClick);

       this.UpdateText ();
   }

   void Update () {
   }


   /// ボタンをクリックした時の処理
   void OnClick() {
     Debug.Log ("Button click!");
     moneyBehaviour.golds -= 200;
     this.UpdateText ();
   }

   void UpdateText(){
       scoreText.text = "golds:" + moneyBehaviour.golds;
   }       

}
```

---

Comment: 実際に上記でがためしてみましたが、goldsからー２００にする計算式はできてますが、ボタンが二つあるので一つをクリックして－２００にしても
もう一つをクリックすると０からの計算になるので、二つとも同じ数字にはならないので、二つのボタンの計算式を引き継がせるにはどうすればいいでしょうか

Comment: ①goldsの値を共通で利用　②複数ボタンで同様のクリック処理を行う、という仕様ケースに修正しました。

Comment: 回答ありがとうございました。